# require_once failed to open stream: No such file or directory - even if relative path seems to be correct(?)

Tags: php, file, path, directory, warnings

Well, I have this dashboard.php file:

```
<?php
require_once ('../resources/config.php');
?>
```

and my file tree looks like this:

/home/name/public_html/

- admin/dashboard.php
- resources/config.php

I really don't know what the heck is wrong with it, I'm using exact same include in the exact same directory for another php script, and everything runs great.

Any ideas?

**EDIT:** I've noticed that in some cases relative path for files called from the same directory on the server is different, and now I know why. I use `index.php` to control URI requests and have nicer URLs, I have a `switch` statement there which use `include` to call requested file, so if it includes a script which also has an include/require statement, the path changes.

I'm trying to fix that now, but I'm very very beginner, so any of your advice will be extremely helpful.

And great thanks to all of you, who answered so far!

Comment: ls -s to show your files privilege.

Comment: if you put `var_dump(realpath('../resources/config.php'));exit;` on the line before your include, what do you get?

Comment: Not sure if I fully understand where you are calling it from, does it work if you just try `./resources/config.php`? Also, you should really just use `require()` rather than `require_once()`, it's more efficient. If you write your code properly, there is almost no good reason for `require_once()`, it will only slow things down.

Comment: @iam-decoder It says `bool(false)`, actually realpath gives me only empty results if I set up a path to another directory, but I tried to echo `realpath('config.php');` and it was pointing to the root directory of my site - just like using `<a href="/config.php"`, so I get rid of '../' for my require and now it works, but... I really don't understand why...

Comment: @Kyle I'm calling it from **rootdir/admin/dashboard.php** to **rootdir/resources/config.php**

Well, this is actually my first project ever, so I'll keep in my mind your advice. :)

Answer (score 1):

I usually use the real path of the file like this:

```
require_once(realpath(dirname(__FILE__)) . '/../../general_controler/database_manager.php');
```

This example is from my *DataImporter* abstract class using a *DatabaseManager* abstract class.

In this example my tree structure looks like this:

(main domain)/PC_administration_interface/Controler/data_importer.php

(main domain)/general_controler/database_manager.php

In your case it would be something like this:

```
require_once (realpath(dirname(__FILE__)) . '/../resources/config.php');
```

Otherwise, starting your path with "/" to start at the root. In Xampp htdocs is the root folder for the site, in my case it could be something like this (as my general_controler folder is directly in the root):

```
require_once('/general_controler/database_manager.php')
```

I guess for you it would be something like (supposing home is a sub folder of the root directory):

```
require_once('/home/name/public_html/resources/config.php');
```

The first solution is probably the best...anyway, you should give it a try.

I hope it will solve your problem,

Jonathan Parent-Lévesque from Montreal